# Setting up custom permalink on a wordpress page with url variables, getting 404 with variable set

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks, custom-wordpress-pages

I have tried alot of answers for the same question here on stackoverflow but I cannot get it to work.

Im going to make a custom profile plugin using the permalink /profile/user. So far I have made a page called "profile" with a shortcode to my plugin, which is currently just printing the username from the url. If I go to website.com/profile?username=test without any changes to functions.php it will load the plugin and display the username.

When I try to rewrite this to a permalink it will give me a 404 error, however I can access $wp->query_vars["username"] so atleast that works. Here is the code I use located in functions.php.

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','mycode_add_rewrite_rules');
function mycode_add_rewrite_rules($rules){
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['profile/([^/]+)/?'] = 'index.php?pagename=profile&username=$matches[1]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}

add_filter('query_vars','mycode_add_rewrite_query_vars');
function mycode_add_rewrite_query_vars($vars){
    array_push($vars, 'username');
    return $vars;
}
```

After reading more about it I also tried adding a add_rewrite_endpoint on the profile

```
add_action('init', 'mycode_add_endpoints');
function mycode_add_endpoints()
{
    add_rewrite_endpoint('profile', EP_PAGES);
}
```

I also tried an endpoint on username aswell without success. I have flushed permalinks everytime I made a change.

Worth noting is that after adding the code to functions.php both the permalink and normal url will give a 404.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this guide: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule#Using_Custom_Templates_with_custom_querystring

However, it still did not work, I then changed the 'username' to another name and it worked. I do not know if that would have worked on my original code but I guess it would. Here is the code I ended up with:

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%unique_username%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);


function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^profile/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=2634&unique_username=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```